# Mac & Google Docs: How to Home?

Tags: macos, text-editing

I'm dying at Mac OSX 10.5.8 + Firefox finding how to go to the beginning of the line in Google Docs

I was cursed with too little intelligence to use this glorified OS. Would any one please guide me in that so dead-simple stuff?

Answer (score 2):

All the basic emacs commands are implemented across OSX:

[image] From: http://www.danrodney.com/mac/

Comment: Ctrl+A invoke search stuff in Firefox and thus won't work

Comment: That's annoying! It should override commands in that way.

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on your browser, but for browsers that follow the Mac standards (including Firefox):

Ctrl+A takes you to the start of the line.
Ctrl+E takes you to the end of the line.
Cmd+Up/Down Arrow takes you to the start/end of the document.
Fn+Up/Down Arrow takes you one page up or down.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "Home" button on your keyboard does what you want. It works on Linux and Windows... maybe it'll work on a mac too.

Edit: And apparently macs don't have a home button. You can try this though:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=489238